# Why does the first character of wchar_t* gets erased when passed to a WinRT component?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, interop

I have a ref class in a WinRT component:

```
namespace WinRTComponent
{
    public ref class Class1 sealed
    {
    public:
        Class1();

        void MyMethod(wchar_t* wcharPtr)
        {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    };
}
```

I also have a Windows Store C++ XAML app, which has reference to the WinRT component. In my app I run the following code:

```
std::wstring str = L"Some text.";
const wchar_t* strPtr = str.data();

WinRTComponent::Class1^ class1 = ref new WinRTComponent::Class1();

wchar_t firstCharBefore = strPtr[0]; // It is 'S', correctly.

class1->MyMethod(const_cast<wchar_t*>(strPtr));

wchar_t firstCharAfter = strPtr[0]; // It is 0! Why?
```

When I pass my wchar_t* pointer to the public method of the WinRT component, the first character of the string gets erased and is changed to 0.

What is the reason for this? Is this expected behaviour or a bug?

Comment: I wouldn't expect anything reasonable if I cast away the const correctness...

Comment: But I cannot make the signature of the component take `const wchar_t*`, because that's apparently not supported by WinRT components (the build error is: `C4400: 'const wchar_t' : const/volatile qualifiers on this type are not supported`).

Comment: Can you try `std::vector<wchar_t> strCpy(str.begin(), str.end())`, and then you can pass the address of the first element as `&strCpy[0]`.  This should eliminate the need to const_cast, and we can see if that's the source of your error

Comment: Strings are never not a problem in C++, the going joke is that every programmer cooks up their own string type.  Much the same in WinRT, you'll need to use Platform::String.  Converting back and forth to std::wstring is covered in this [background article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166929.aspx)

Comment: I can simply convert the `wstring` to a `Platform::String` and it works properly, but that copies the string to a new instance every time I call this componenet, which I would like to avoid. That's why I simply would like to pass a pointer.

Comment: Dave the same thing happens with the copied vector, its first item is set to zero (but the other items are intact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is occurring because a public method `void MyMethod(wchar_t* wcharPtr)` on a `ref class` isn't a function that takes an input string, it's a function that has a `wchar_t` out parameter.  In other words, to WinRT `MyMethod` is a function that returns a 16-bit character.  So my guess is that the WinRT ABI machinery is either blanking out the value before giving it to `MyMethod`, or it's detecting that your implementation of `MyMethod` never assigns to it and generates code that assigns it a default value.

The key takeaway is that pointer parameters on a public method of a `ref class` mean **output**, not pointer input.  Pointers can't cross the ABI boundary, only WinRT types can.  The C++ type `wchar_t` maps to the WinRT 16-bit character type so it's okay, and pointer parameters are the way that C++/CX implements WinRT output parameters because that's the most natural way for C++ to return data via parameters.

To write a public method of a component that takes a string input value in C++/CX, you have to use `Platform::String^` as the argument type.  If you call this function from C++/CX you can avoid making a copy by passing a `StringReference`:

```
WinRTComponent::Class1^ class1 = ref new WinRTComponent::Class1();
class1->MyMethod(Platform::StringReference(strPtr));
```

If you do that, you should find that calling `Data()` on the `String^` inside `MyMethod` gets you the same `strPtr` that you passed in.

See the "StringReference" section of the [C++/CX strings documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699879%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) for more info about it.

Comment: You're right, thanks. Since then I got another answer at the Microsoft forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3e8b8b27-e50a-408e-a76a-ed9e0305a965/why-does-the-first-character-of-wchart-gets-erased-when-passed-to-a-winrt-component#ff47f0a8-7e7f-4ee1-b501-783bc05c12e9 "COM rules say out params must be stabilized to zero. if there is a marshaling layer in between it might be implementing that for you."